# Elements to be cut when reach Navbar area by scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css

hope someone can help me out with this one. I have a fixed navbar with no background color and a specific height. Now when scrolling up/down, I want the Elements to be cut at the navbar border (red marked in graphic example), so they don't show up in the navbar area. Is there a Javascript solution for that?

Here is a graphic example how it should behave.
[image: before scrolling]
[image: when cutting elements at navbar border]

Thanks for any hint.

Update: After Hijiki Mizukusa hint my final code for this solution looks like this...

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}

html {
  background: url("Background.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

nav {
  height: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

nav div {
  background-color: yellow;
  margin: 0 20px;
  padding: 5px;
}

img {
  height: 300px;
}

section {
  display: flex;
}

#content {
  position:fixed;
  top: 50px;
  overflow: scroll;
  height: calc(100% - 50px);
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0px;
  background: transparent; /* make scrollbar transparent */
}
```

```html
<body>

  <nav>
    <div><a href="#About">About</a></div>
    <div><a href="#Products">Products</a></div>
    <div><a href="#Shop">Shop</a></div>
    <div><a href="#Carrer">Carrer</a></div>
  </nav>

  <div id="content">
    <section>
      <div>
        <img src="Cat.jpg" alt="Cat">
      </div>
      <div>
        What is Lorem Ipsum?
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

        Why do we use it?
        It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).

        Where can I get some?
        There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a dictionary of over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc.
      </div>
    </section>
    <section>
      <div>
        <img src="Cat.jpg" alt="Cat">
      </div>
      <div>
        What is Lorem Ipsum?
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

        Why do we use it?
        It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).

        Where can I get some?
        There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a dictionary of over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc.
      </div>
    </section>
    <section>
      <div>
        <img src="Cat.jpg" alt="Cat">
      </div>
      <div>
        What is Lorem Ipsum?
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

        Why do we use it?
        It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).

        Where can I get some?
        There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a dictionary of over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc.
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
    

</body>
```

With ::-webkit-scrollbar I also managed to hide the scrollbar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript is not necessary and I guess CSS solution is more preferable.

If your navbar height would not vary during page running, you can just set the content's position to fixed and have height calc(100% - the navbar height), top as the navbar height.

Let say you navbar's height is 50px:

```css
#navbar, #content{
  position:fixed;
  left: 0;
  background: transparent;
}

#navbar{
  top: 0;
  height: 50px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

#content{
  top: 50px;
  height: calc(100% - 50px);
  overflow: auto;
}

#body{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, grey, black); 
}

#navbar>li{
  display: inline-block;
  background: yellow;
  margin: 0 15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="body">
  <ul id="navbar">
     <li>About</li>  
     <li>Products</li> 
     <li>Shop</li> 
     <li>Career</li> 
  </ul>
  <div id="content">
    <p>What is Lorem Ipsum?
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

        Why do we use it?
        It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).


        Where does it come from?
        Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.

        The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.

        Where can I get some?
        There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a dictionary of over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you do not sure the height of the navbar, you can use flex layout.

```css
#body{
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, grey, black); 
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#navbar, #content{
  background: transparent;
}

#navbar{
  list-style-type: none;
}

#content{
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow: auto;
}



#navbar>li{
  display: inline-block;
  background: yellow;
  margin: 0 15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="body">
  <ul id="navbar">
     <li>About</li>  
     <li>Products</li> 
     <li>Shop</li> 
     <li>Career</li> 
  </ul>
  <div id="content">
    <p>What is Lorem Ipsum?
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

        Why do we use it?
        It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).


        Where does it come from?
        Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.

        The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.

        Where can I get some?
        There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a dictionary of over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Hijiki, you were totally right, by fixing the content position and calculate the height.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need javascript, you can add

```
position: sticky;
top: 0;
```

In CSS (on your navbar)

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you navbar elements are fixed as they belong to the navbar so the scroll will not affect them.

> A simple way to solve this would be to not fix the navbar and to add instead a fixed red link  to simulate the border of this navbar. This would allow those elements to go away on scroll but to keep that red division line on its place.

Hope this helped :D

Answer (score 0):

No need for javascript, You can just add the same background as the page to the nav element via css.

Create something like a `<div class="background-container"></div>` within the navbar, scale it to viewport so the background is identical to the one of the page itself and then hide the excess part by setting `overflow: hidden` on the nav bar.

Answer (score 0):

So, to achieve what you want with pure CSS , you need to make a few "Hacks", I made a quick demo which shows, how something like that can be achieved.

1. Create a sticky nav;
2. Create a element with the same background image as the body inside (with the same height as the image);
3. Make the nav with overflow-hidden;
4. Place the image at the top of the page.

Take a look at the demo:

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
  height: 200vh;
}

nav{
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  height: 30px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  width: 100vw;
}

ul{
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-image: url("https://p.bigstockphoto.com/eIdTXLbqQilMs9xbjvcs_bigstock-Aerial-View-Of-Sandy-Beach-Wit-256330393.jpg");
  background-size: 100vw 100vh;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

img{
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>About</li>
        <li>Section</li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<main>
    <img src="https://p.bigstockphoto.com/eIdTXLbqQilMs9xbjvcs_bigstock-Aerial-View-Of-Sandy-Beach-Wit-256330393.jpg" alt="">
</main>
```